# A line of lights in sky

Tags: star

I just seen this in sky a line of stars probably satellites just wondering what they where and what they doing it was amazing never seen any like it [image]

Comment: At least this question comes with a photograph of the phenomenon, which I haven't seen in any of the dozens of other questions about sightings of Starlink satellites. It would be nice if we could merge that into the original question somehow.

Comment: @antispinwards when I look closely, every spot has a trail. If there were many fixed points and a few trails, that's one thing, but this could just be camera motion (the trails are not even straight!)